# How can I get the installation information about SAS?

Tags: installation, sas

When I batch run a SAS program, I want to know where are SAS installed and pass this information to a macro variable.
Is there any system option or global macro variable available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SASROOT (the install location of SAS) should be an environmental variable.

```
%Put sasroot = %sysget(sasroot);
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that %sysget() is sometimes case sensitive - see my EG 4.3 (linux) log:

```
15         %put %sysget(SASROOT);
/opt/sas/env2/lev1/software/SASFoundation/9.2
16         %put %sysget(sasroot);
WARNING: The argument to macro function %SYSGET is not defined as a system variable.
```

Strangely, its **not** case sensitive in base sas 9.3 (windows).

You can see more set options using:

```
%put %sysfunc(getoption(set));
```

Or even the following:

```
filename set pipe 'set';
data _null_;
  infile set;
  input;
  put _infile_;
run;
```

(works in both linux & windows)

Answer (score -1):

SAS as 'Statistical Analysis System'? have you tried 'ls -ls `which sas`'? if SAS executable is installed on the system and I can call it like $ sas maybe it has a soft link to /bin or /local/bin with 'ls -ls' you can know where that soft-link is pointing to.

Comment: 'SAS' no longer stands for anything. visit sas.com for more information about SAS.

Comment: ohh,  it's been years (+15) I haven't use SAS, was great then, but after I knew SPPS I simple stop using it